# flink gives me "too may open files" on checkpoint

Tags: java, flink-streaming, checkpoint

I'm running same streaming jobs several time but with different parameters. The task use key state to just calculate the difference between the current event and the last one received and send it to the same topic of Kafka (I know is not logical or common but is not my decision).  After several test everything works well until an hour later that I get this exceptions:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:227)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:730)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:295)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for WindowOperator_306d8342cb5b2ad8b53f1be57f65bee8_(1/3) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:137)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:276)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:132)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/quantion/flink-checkpoints/PeriodDailyAvrgValuePeak/1cb1374a0ea7dc9d74f86a8de9be3bec/chk-1/3274bb7c-0352-4367-87bc-9f85939f00b3 (Too many open files)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.<init>(LocalDataInputStream.java:50)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:142)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.open(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:80)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FileStateHandle.openInputStream(FileStateHandle.java:68)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupsStateHandle.openInputStream(KeyGroupsStateHandle.java:112)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restorePartitionedState(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:340)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:315)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:95)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:151)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:123)
... 7 more
```

more

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:765)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:633)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:615)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09PartitionDiscoverer.initializeConnections(Kafka09PartitionDiscoverer.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.open(AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.open(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:469)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:420)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:296)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:129)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:156)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:160)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:701)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:127)
... 14 more
```

I checked the leader of the topic is correct, as I saw in a similar question, but everything seems good.

I already try to increase the number of files that the system can handle with **ulimit -n** but the error still remain.

I also delete manually several checkpoint files as I keep them on cancelation but didn't have any impact so far.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // set up checkpoint
    CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
    config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
    env.setStateBackend((StateBackend) new FsStateBackend("file:///home/quantion/flink-checkpoints/diferential-checkpoints"));
    env.enableCheckpointing(3600000);

    if (args.length != 3) throw new Exception("Needs some arguments:\n" +
                "file.jar <dev_type> <sensor_type> <new_label>");

    // get arguments
    Arguments arguments = new Arguments(args);
    String TYPE = arguments.getTYPE();
    String TARGET = arguments.getTARGET();
    String NEW_LABEL = arguments.getNEW_LABEL();

    // Propiedades Kafka
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", HOST+":9092");
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", HOST+":2181");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", TYPE); //TYPE
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DifferentialConsumption.class);

    DataStream<String> inputStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(TOPIC, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
            .name("Read Kafka source --topic "+TOPIC);

    DataStream<JSONObject> jsonObjectDataStream = inputStream.map(x -> {
        try {
            return new JSONObject(x);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("An {} occurred.", "error", e);
            return new JSONObject();
        }
    }).name("Parse events to JSONObjects");

    DataStream<JSONObject> filterStream = jsonObjectDataStream.filter(x -> x.has("type") && x.get("type").equals(TYPE) && !x.has(NEW_LABEL))
            .name("Filter events by type: "+TYPE+" and don't have "+NEW_LABEL+" already");

    DataStream<JSONObject> saveSate = filterStream.keyBy(x -> x.getString("id")).flatMap(new Diferential(TARGET, NEW_LABEL))
            .name("KeyedState for differential");
    DataStream<String> streamToString = saveSate.map(JSONObject::toString)
            .name("Parse JSON to String");

    FlinkKafkaProducer011<String> myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>(HOST+":9092", TOPIC, new SimpleStringSchema());
    streamToString.addSink(myProducer).name("Write Kafka sink --topic "+TOPIC);
    //streamToString.print();

    // execute program
    env.execute("Get differential for "+TYPE);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this "too many open files" problem, but maybe you can solve this from why this file is not found. And does this occur every time you restart?

Answer (score 0):

A malformed messages keeps all the jobs on recovering and reopening files from checkpoint, so even when I restarted Flink, the error still remains.

For this case I add a `JSONObject.has()` to check if the argument existed before reading it and the jobs could recover from the checkpoints after rebooting the Flink node.

A possible alternative solution was to restart the offsets in Kafka but this could lead to lose some events.